# unterminated regular expression literal js error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, regex

I have added jQuery validator add method for the presence of http check in url field.

JS

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("valid_url", function(value, element) {
 if(!/^(https?|ftp):\/\/i.test(val))
    val = 'http://'+val; // set both the value
    $(elem).val(val); // also update the form element
 }
```

My Console throws
**"unterminated regular expression literal"** error in the following line.

```
if(!/^(https?|ftp):\/\/i.test(val))
```

What my mistake is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regular expression literals should be surrounded by the delimiters(`/`). There's no terminating delimiter:

```
/^(https?|ftp):\/\//i
//                 ^
```

---

For example:

```
>> /^(https?|ftp):\/\//i.test('http://stackoverflow.com/')
true
>> /^(https?|ftp):\/\//i.test('telnet://stackoverflow.com/')
false
```

Comment: When I add /  if(!(/^(https?|ftp):\/\//i.test(val))) { everything after // is commented. So that condition check does not work

Comment: @Sam, It's strange, I tested it in Chrome, node.js. And both give me the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get this error if you're simply attempting to concatenate a variable that utilizes a regular expression and forget a quotation mark somewhere.